# Replace the middle part of a string with a new one

Tags: javascript

I have a string as follows:

```
var email = "name(replace these parenthesis by @)domain.com"
```

How can I replace the part `(replace these parenthesis by @)` with @ using javascript?

Comment: "Replace *with*", not "replace by".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use regex if you are sure of the pattern. Every character between **(** and **@)** will be replaced with a **@**

```
var str = "name(replace these parenthesis by @)domain.com";
var patt1 = /\(.*@\)/i;
document.write(str.replace(patt1,"@"));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
email.replace("(replace these parenthesis by @)", "@")
```

Comment: Power question, power answer.

Comment: That won't work ... I just gave an example. What I need is to replace everything between the parenthesis, including it, by @

Comment: It works. The result is the returned value http://jsfiddle.net/CSQLQ/1/ . Any additional details should have been included in the question, I guess =)

Answer (score 1):

for the string format you are presenting:

```
var email = "name(replace these parenthesis by @)domain.com";
```

doing this:

```
email.replace(/\(.*\)/g,"@");
```

will give

```
name@domain.com
```

Answer (score 0):

If the content is as you have mentioned `(replace these paranthesis by @)` you can replace it like:

```
var email = "name(replace these parenthesis by @)domain.com";
email.replace(/(replace these parenthesis by @)/g,"@");
```

Or are you looking at something more generic?